# Connect 2 apps with bluetooth and transmit data flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

So I am making an app where I need to transmit data from one app to another app (Preferrable using bluetooth). Ive looked into the bluetooth plugin but I cant seem to understand how to do a connection between 2 devices and transfer some strings. Can somebody help? Id prefer a solution through bluetooth but if there isn't, please suggest something else
I need to develop on android 7 API 24

I did some research, and it looks like the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial package is good for this. But Im unable to get the chat system in test app working. Can somebody help me out with that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no easy way. You must learn at least some basics of Bluetooth protocol if you want to work with it successfully. Of course, don't waste time trying to implement Bluetooth from scratch. Use packages and you will learn everything while writing code, reading documentation and debugging.

I'm using [Flutter Blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) package. It works both with other phones and any auxiliary devices. Example in description works perfectly. Everything that goes on top should be custom to your app; therefore there is no need to look for other code snippets.

Working with Bluetooth may be harder because the hardware component is involved. In cases like that debugging complexity grows exponentially. Split the process into smaller parts and you will be okey: scanning, detection, address read, connection, and so on.

This is a general code snippet to scan available devices. If the device is detected- the name is represented.

```
class BleScan extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BleScanState createState() => _BleScanState();
}

class _BleScanState extends State<BleScan> {
  BluetoothService service;
  int scanDuration = 10; // seconds

  @override
  void initState() {
    FlutterBlue.instance.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: scanDuration));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text('Search again if not detected'),
        ),
        StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
          stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
          initialData: [],
          builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
            children: snapshot.data
                .where((t) => t.device.name.contains(serialNumberMap[chosenSerial])) //Filter by name
                .map(
                  (r) => Text(r.device.name),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<bool>(
              stream: FlutterBlue.instance.isScanning,
              initialData: false,
              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data) {
                  return Container();
                } else {
                  return FloatingActionButton.extended(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    label: Text('Search again'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      FlutterBlue.instance.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: scanDuration));
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This snippet can be used to connect to the device, read services and characteristics. Take a note that characteristic is a location where data exchange is happening [as documented everywhere](https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/tutorial-intro-to-developing-bluetooth-smart-applications-for-android-716).

```
widget.device.connect(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5), autoConnect: false).then((a) {
  widget.device.discoverServices().then((value) {
    value.forEach((service) {
      //services are here
      service.characteristics.forEach((characteristic) {
        //characteristics
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample code on how I can use flutter_blue to do a phone to phone connection? There isnt like a send data option, only writing/ reading services. Im happy to learn the basics of bluetooth protocol, any article you would suggest?

Comment: Ive already used the flutter blue plugin to connect 2 phones, just cannot understand how to do the data transfer

Comment: Sure. Check my edit.

Comment: Thank you, Ill test this code and see if it leads me to the solution. But you also have showed me how to read the data, not write it, that's the main problem I faced. Ill read the documentation you have provided and see if I can find anything in that, but in the meantime if you could tell me how to "create" a characteristic, I would really appreciate it. I dont want to cut off on doing work, but its just that Ive been trying to do this for very long but cant seem to understand how

Comment: It's analog to reading (characteristic.write(data))

Comment: So that'll create the characteristic too? Wow I didnt think it would do that before. Will test

Comment: Not create, but write into it. Think of service as a car and characteristic as a seat in it. One service has multiple characteristics. When you want to send information, you put it on the seat. It is like a storage unit. Others will see that the seat is not empty anymore; therefore, new data available.

Comment: Hey, I know I am reaching out after a lot of time but I had been using other methods. I still cannot get it working. I read a lot about how bluetooth works, now I realise I need to create a central and peripheral. Flutter_blue acts aas central but I cant find a good peripheral package. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

#### First Idea

It depends on the kind of data/experience you want to provide, but the easiest solution to share datas between apps in different devices is with QR Codes.
Your device A generates a QR Code.
Device B scans the QR Code from Device A and retrieves the datas.

Pros :

- Easy to implement
- Works in Airplane Mode
- Every phone has a camera
- Doesn't affect the battery

Cons :

- Requires a user's action
- Won't work if you have a very large file to transmit between phones

#### Second Idea

If you need to transmit the datas silently between two phones and that the upload/download may take some time, you could use the Bluetooth as you thought, and this library should fit your needs.
https://pub.dev/packages/nearby_connections

The flow would be the following :

1. Pairing devices
2. Establishing a connection
3. Uploading the datas to the target device's memory (on the SD Card or phone's internal memory) => The datas will be written in a file
4. On the target's devices, listen to the changes on a specific folder, and retrieve the datas written on the specific file

Pros :

- No action required by the target device
- Silent
- Can handle large files

Cons :

- Only works on Android phones
- Harder to develop / maintain

#### Third Idea

If you can use the internet, you could relay on Firebase Realtime Database.

Pros :

- No need to be close to the target device
- Quick, easy to implement and to scale

Cons :

- Requires internet
- Can only share "String" datas or light encoded media files

I'll update my answer if I can think about another solution

Comment: Im sorry, all 3 are really good ideas but do not work for me. 1.I need to transfer data back and forth, 2. One of the devices can be iOS, I already tried it out. 3. The data I need to transfer is about the wifi credentials. Im looking into using the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nearby_connections package. Seems good right now