Bluetooth Classic Flutter App - read and write
I'm developing an app that needs to read data from a connected Bluetooth device.  The device is already paired with my phone, and I'm aiming to use Bluetooth Classic for communication.
I've tried several libraries/packages, but haven't found one that works perfectly for my needs.
I'd appreciate any assistance you can offer.  Would anyone be able to recommend libraries or point me in the right direction?
I tried some packages: flutter Bluetooth serial
Bluetooth classic
Bluetooth all

this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/70289320/6193799
